# Problem with toggle led on Arduino nano Atmega328P with timer/counter0 interrupt

Tags: timer, arduino, interrupt, atmega, microchip

I try to toggle the LED on Arduino nano ATmega328P without success.
(Timer 0 is `8bit` timer)

I managed to execute it with `Timer 1`
with code [from here](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=276106.0).

```c
#define ledPin 13
void setup() {
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  cli(); // disable interrupts
  TCCR0A = 0;
  TCCR0B = 0;
  TCCR0B |= (1 << CS02 | 1 << CS00); //clkI/O/1024
  TIMSK0 = 0;
  TIMSK0 |= (1 << TOIE0); // Overflow Interrupt Enable
  TCNT0 = 0;
  sei(); // enable interrupts
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

ISR(TIM0_OVF_vect) {
  digitalWrite(ledPin, digitalRead(ledPin) ^ 1);
}

void loop() {

}
```

I also tried to change the interrupt vector to: TIMER0_OVF_vect

and got this error:

```
Arduino: 1.8.9 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Nano, ATmega328P (Old Bootloader)"

wiring.c.o (symbol from plugin): In function `__vector_16':

(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__vector_16'

sketch\tests.ino.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino Nano.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.
```

I expect the led to toggle.

Comment: The LED looks like it should be toggling 16000000/1024/256 = 61 times per second. Are you sure that it's not actually flashing that fast and that you just can't see it?

Comment: I tried to add another delay inside the ISR still no blink.
I also tried to Serial.print("hi"); inside it, the interrupt never occurs

Comment: It's not safe to do Serial.print in an ISR anyway.

Comment: also tried to change the interrupt vector to: TIMER0_OVF_vect
got this problem:

Arduino: 1.8.9 (Windows 10), Board: "Arduino Nano, ATmega328P (Old Bootloader)"

wiring.c.o (symbol from plugin): In function `__vector_16':

(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__vector_16'

sketch\tests.ino.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here

collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino Nano.

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first block of code with:

```
ISR(TIM0_OVF_vect) {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, digitalRead(ledPin) ^ 1);
}
```

has the wrong ISR name. `TIM0_OVF_vect` is only valid for some ATtiny microcontrollers. You can find a complete list of interrupts and which controllers they are used with [here](https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__interrupts.html).

You then tried to change it to use `TIMER0_OVF_vect`, which is valid for the ATMEGA328P, but you cannot use this with Arduino, because Arduino ATMEGA328P builds use `Timer0` for `millis()` and related timing. This is why you get a `multiple definition of` error - the linker is telling you that there are two `TIMER0_OVF_vect` ISRs defined by your program (one by your sketch, one in wiring.c).

`Timer2` is not used by default, so you should be able to use that instead. The only default Arduino library that used `Timer2` is the `Tone` library.